How to differentiate $x''=f_t+f_xf$?
I'm studying initial values problems and I've been struggling with this problem for a month.
I would really appreciate it if you could give me some help.
Here's the problem.
If $x'=f(t,x)$ and $x$ is a function dependent on $t$, then
$x''=Df$, $x'''=D^2f+f_xDff$
where $D= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}+f\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$,
$D^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}+2f\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial t}+f^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$.
And here is the way I expanded the formula.
$\begin{align}x''(t) &=\frac{d}{dt}f \\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f\frac{dx}{dt} \\
&=f_t+f_xf \\
&=Df \end{align}$
$\begin{align}x'''(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}(f_t+f_xf) \quad &\cdots (1)\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}f_t+\frac{d}{dt}(f_xf) \quad &\cdots (2) \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}f_t+(\frac{d}{dt}f_x)f +f_x(\frac{d}{dt}f) \quad &\cdots (3)\\
&=(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f_t+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_t\frac{dx}{dt})
+ (\frac{\partial}{\partial t}f_x+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_x\frac{dx}{dt})f
+ f_x(Df) \quad &\cdots (4) \\
&=(f_{tt}+f_{tx}f)+(f_{xt}+f_{xx}f)f+f_xDf \quad &\cdots (5) \\ 
&=f_{tt}+f_{tx}f+f_{xt}f+f_{xx}f^2+f_xDf \quad &\cdots (6) \\
&=f_{tt}+2f_{tx}f+f_{xx}f^2+f_xDf \quad &\cdots (7) \\
&=D^2f+f_xDf \quad &\cdots (8)
\end{align}$
I am supposed to show that $x'''=D^2f+f_xDff$, but I keep getting the result $x'''=D^2f+f_xDf$. I don't know why I keep getting a result that is missing one $f$. I really feel dumb.
I would be really grateful if you could help me figure out where I made a mistake. Thank you.

You've expanded the expression correctly, the additional $f$ might be a typo from your source.

You can check your result using dimensional analysis. Let the dimension of $x,t$ be $L,T$ respectively. Then $[x'] = L/T$. Further $[x'''] = L/T^3$ which agrees with the first term $[D^2f] = (L/T)/T^2$ and also the second term $[f_xDf] = (L/T)/L \cdot (L/T)/T$. If you add another $f$ in then the dimensions do not agree.

That was quite unexpected. Maybe I shouldn't have trusted the textbook completely. Thank you, by the way.
